# Can name munging be avoided for an interop call in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

In advanced compilation

```
(js/console.log "HELLO"
  js/window.navigator.msSaveBlob
  (.. js/window -navigator -msSaveBlob)
  (aget js/window "navigator" "msSaveBlob")
  js/console.log)
```

=>
HELLO undefined undefined function function

I think this means that js/console has some provided externs, but navigator does not (or at least not the ms specific stuff).

AFAIK the only way to avoid this is to create some externs? But this seems unnecessarily obtuse; why would you ever want js/anything to be munged?? Wouldn't it make make more sense to never munge js/anything interop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System functions are not munged; only your own functions are. You probably want `(.log js/console ...)` ?

For de-munging your own functions, place `^:export` between the `defn` and the function name to export its name intact.

[Here](https://blog.8thlight.com/taryn-sauer/2014/07/31/clojurescript-faux-pas.html) is more information.

All see the section called "munging" [here](http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html).